# sorting 2 files and applying a command on them

Tags: bash, shell

I want to find non-unique lines from 2 unsorted files(say file1 and file2). I have to run 3 commands for it.

sort file1 > file1_sort
sort file2 > file2_sort
comm -3 file1_sort file2_sort

Can I do it without making temporary files and in a single command?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description does not match the commands you have. You say you want non-unique lines, but have `comm -3` which removes the non-unique lines.

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -d
sort file1 file2 | uniq -u
```

The first line gives you the non-unique lines (i.e. those that are in both file1 and file2). The second line gives you the unique lines (i.e. those that appear only in file1 or file2 but not both).

Answer (score 4):

```
comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that process substitution is not standard (is not available in all *Bourne* type shells).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in non unique lines try this:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to sort at all.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1}NR>FNR{if($0 in a)print $0}' file1 file2 > result.file
```